# Conditionally Return the Value of a Column

Tags: google-sheets

I've a sheet with product names (rows) and months (columns) and value representing unit sales for each product:

```
Product ｜ First Order Date ｜Jan-07 ｜ Feb-07 ｜ March-07 ｜   April-07  ｜
A       ｜   April-07       ｜   -   ｜  -     ｜    -     ｜    123      ｜
B       ｜   Jan-07         ｜  252  ｜  123   ｜   545    ｜    454      ｜
```

The first order column is populated dynamically with the following formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($1:$1,,SMALL(IF(T2:FC2<>"-",COLUMN(T2:FC2),""),1))), 1, 1)
```

For the sake of cleaning up the structure of the data and facilitating better updates and maintenance, I'd like to move all of the order data out of the table and create two tables:

```
Product ｜ First Order Date ｜
A       ｜   April-07       ｜
B       ｜   Jan-07         ｜


Product ｜Jan-07 ｜ Feb-07 ｜ March-07 ｜   April-07  ｜
A       ｜    -  ｜  -     ｜    -     ｜    123      ｜
B       ｜  252  ｜  123   ｜   545    ｜    454      ｜
```

However, I'm not sure how I can adapt the formula to reference the new sheet and a lookup to search for the product name.

Comment: Excel? Google Sheets? Some other spreadsheet product? Use the appropriate tags.

Comment: Maybe you will find it out after cutting the data and pasting them into another sheet. Theoretically google or excel will change the reference automatically.

Comment: Nice idea, but didn't work I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that using the multiple table approach is really that helpful, but then you have to live with your data, so you know best.

The following formula returns the First Order Date.
You can put it, as-is, in your existing "First Order Date" column OR in new "First Order Date" Table.

```
=INDEX(D$14:G$14,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(D15:G15),0),0))
```

- Modify the columns to cover the actual date range for your data (T to FC2, I think)
- Modify the row number to reflect your data. The first instance is the row containing the column header; the second instance is the row number of product A.
- Once you've edited it for Product A, you can just copy it down as many rows as you have products.

*Credit*: Adapted from "[find first numeric value in range](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/432492-find-first-numeric-value-range.html)" by sanrv1f, 27-11-2009

Comment: Forgot to add. How to “lookup” product name”? Simple formula: =cell address, like “=C3”. Doesn’t have to be more complicated than that.